# How to redirect React app to non-www HTTPS?

Tags: reactjs, apache, .htaccess

I am coding a React app which I deployed on my webserver. I have the following .htaccess file which servers all requests via the index file because I am using client sided routing:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

which works.

I would however want to redirect all traffic to HTTPS non-www. Could someone guide me in the right directions using the standard .htaccess file but via index.html:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

Answer (score 3):

Easiest to break down what you already have (which does the opposite)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
```

Matches when the request is not done through https... pretty simple. The [OR] at the end means that either this rule or the one below it must return true.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
```

this matches if there's no "www." at the start of the request (`^` means the start, `!` means "not"). `[NC]` means "nocase" so basically just ignores the case. Not necessary on linux servers but still recommended.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
```

So once either HTTPS is off or the string doesn't start with `www.`, the HTTP_HOST is passed into this rule. This rule will always return true as the regex matches an OPTIONAL "www." (because of the `?` after the paren), then one or more and character (`.+`) until the end of the string (`$`).

The `.+` part after the optional `www.` is wrapped in parens to capture it ( `(?:` before it signifies a non-capturing group, so the rest of the host name is captured as `%1` - or the first captured group).

```
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

This then rewrites the request, to include `https://www.` plus the rest of the host name `$1` and then the REQUEST_URI, which is everything from the first `/` in the URI.

The bit at the end of the rule is also pretty simple, `L` means this is the last rewrite rule, `NE` means `noescape` - this is useful when including the request_uri to prevent it being escaped. `R=301` means redirect with a 301 status.

---

**TLDR - Your solution**

So to create the rule that you need to drop the www., you should flip a couple of those options:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

On the second `RewriteCond` we remove the `!` to make it match a  url that DOES start with `www.`, then on the `RewriteRule` we remove the www. that's being added in.